# SSH Via Ethernet Without Internet Sharing

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, headless, macos

I am working on a project that uses an SSH connection via ethernet to the Raspberry Pi. Currently I am doing this by enabling internet sharing via ethernet on my computer (OSX El Capitan). The point of doing this is that the end product (which will be running headless) is meant to be portable, and able to do this type of communication regardless of what wifi network the user may be on.

So far this works well, except that I have to turn on internet sharing in system preferences, which is not only kind of an ugly step for the end user, but is also not allowed on some networks depending on security settings. The fact that the PC has to be connected to wifi at all is somewhat non-ideal.

I was wondering if there was a way (such as by creating some sort of local network on the PC) that I could avoid this process, as well as the necessity of the PC being connected to any sort of wifi at all.

Does anyone have a good recommendation for a solution and or resources on the subject?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague, and lacking any real detail, so a definitive answer is not possible. As mentioned in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
the current Raspbian allows `ssh` over a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) . This certainly works from a Mac. Other options are to set a static IP address, although this has its own problems.

Answer (score 1):

On mac press (command + k) to open Connect to Server window. Then just type the 
IP address , username and password.